# Cache replacement using lru fifo and lfu

Tags: caching

- assumed that every instructions occupied one block
- size of cache is 3 block

`````
x = 0
y = 1
z = 2
m = x + z
n = x + y
o = n + m
p = m + y
q = n + z
o = m + q````

show the replacement (if any) from the begining untill finish
a. Using LRU
b. Using FIFO
c. Using LFU

Cache replacement
for this problem
`````